# Convert a for loop into a map() function approach in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am wondering how to convert a for loop into a map() function approach. Any efficient way to iterate over a list is more than welcome!

```
import feedparser
import pandas as pd

alist = [
    "http://finance.yahoo.com/rss/topstories",
    "http://www.marketwatch.com/rss/topstories"
]


for x in alist:
    f = feedparser.parse(x)
    data = pd.DataFrame(f.entries)
```

Comment: Since you're reassigning to `data`, it wouldn't work here. But I assume you're current code is actually incorrect, and you'd want something like `data.append(pd.DataFrame(f.entries))`.

Comment: Use a list comprehension: `data = [pd.DataFrame(feedparser.parse(x)) for x in alist]`. Don't use `map`, since there are already two functions involved.

Comment: But seen my above list comprehension example includes a nested function (`parse` inside a constructor), I think your current loop is actually fine.

Comment: Just converting a for loop iteration of a list to *comprehension* or `map` doesn't make it more efficient.

Comment: You're right that list comprehension might do better in this case. @9769953

Comment: You're right that list comprehension might do better in this case. @ThePyGuy

Comment: No, whether it's `map`, normal `for` loop iteration, or comprehension, none of them provides better efficiency than other for your use case, because You are asking for *Any efficient way to iterate over a list*. All of those methods have same level of efficiency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply create a function and pass the list element and call it from map.

```
import feedparser
import pandas as pd

alist = [
    "http://finance.yahoo.com/rss/topstories",
    "http://www.marketwatch.com/rss/topstories"
]


def func(x):
    f = feedparser.parse(x)
    data = pd.DataFrame(f.entries)
    return data

print(list(map(func, alist)))
```